# Cannot Connect to Https

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, https

Hello Guys I have trouble connecting my site to https,, it always says ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT, the weird part is I have allowed my server and firewall to open port 443,

I have windows server 2016 Datacenter, 
i netstat -a and i found port 443 listening, 
I have Apache 2.4,

I thought it was ok because on my testing server, https is working with the same setup

but on this I cannot find the answer, My server is on AWS, with ports 443, 22 and 80 open on security group

I been struggling for 1 week, please someone help, I can provide any information

Comment: Have you applied appropriate SSL handshake mechanism in your https call? Do you use self signed certificate or CA certificate?

Comment: I have CA certificate from letsencrypt.. well I am beginner, What I did was edit httpd-ssl into proper format, like editing the path for the certificate file

Comment: Have you checked the ssl port assigned in the server?

Comment: Well I believe its port 443

Comment: I have an Update, https works on localhost, but online its not

Comment: Then it is probably not an issue with apache server. Check if there is any ip restriction in AWS that may not allow all requests even if port is open.

Comment: Can you share your AWS configuration ? ELB ? EIP ?